# jsoup Java, брать только текст элемента верхнего уровня

Tags: java, html, jsoup, css-selectors

Обрабатываю тело html документа и мне необходимо брать текст одного из элементов td - "*Название организации*", а "*Старое название организации*" внутри **span** брать не надо, пример:

```
<tr>      
<td>Название</td>
<td>*Название организации*<span class="oldValue">*Старое название организации*</span></td>
</tr>
```

На данный момент я пытался использовать следующий код:

```
doc.select("td:contains(Название)+td").text()
```

Но проблема в том, что он также берет текст внутри элемента **span**.
Подскажите, может быть есть ли возможность брать текст только элемента верхнего уровня и не брать текст его дочернего элемента?
Или брать сам родительский элемент без дочернего и уже из него извлекать текст?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, как решить свою проблему, можно предварительно изменять html документ, удаляя из него элемент **span** внутри **td** с нужным текстом:

```
doc.getElementsByClass("oldValue").remove();
// или так:
doc.select("td:contains(Название)+td>span").remove();
```

Получаю:

```
<tr>      
<td>Название</td>
<td>*Название организации*</td>
</tr>
```